# Sqlalchemy: for loop over related collection skips items

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I'm trying to iterate through a related collection (`user.addresses` below), and disassociate all of them from the parent `User`. When I set a breakpoint in the loop, my debugger shows the collection has say 3 items, but advancing execution may only hit the breakpoint one more time. In all of my testing it has never iterated through the whole collection. This reflects in the DELETE statements, it does not delete all related Addresses.

I striped/trimmed down this code from a fastapi project.

```py
from sqlalchemy import String, ForeignKey, select, delete
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    DeclarativeBase,
    Mapped,
    mapped_column,
    relationship,
    selectinload,
)

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_account"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    fullname: Mapped[str | None]

    addresses: Mapped[list["Address"]] = relationship(back_populates="user", cascade="save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"User(id={self.id!r}, name={self.name!r}, fullname={self.fullname!r})"


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = "address"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    email_address: Mapped[str]
    user_id = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user_account.id"))

    user: Mapped[User] = relationship(back_populates="addresses")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Address(id={self.id!r}, email_address={self.email_address!r})"

async def update_user(id: int, new_user, db: AsyncSession) -> User:
    result = await db.scalars(select(User).filter_by(id=id).options(selectinload(User.addresses)))
    user = result.first()

    # not relevant to question
    if user is None:
        pass

    user.name = new_user.name
    user.fullname = new_user.fullname

    for address in user.addresses:
        address.user = None  # BREAKPOINT HERE
    
    for address in new_user.addresses:
        db.add(Address(email_address=address.email_address, user=user))

    await db.flush()
    return user
```

Comment: As Yurii's answer states, the issue is that changing `address.user` also alters `user.addresses` in SQLAlchemy, so you're altering the structure you're iterating over. However, I would back up and ask: what exactly are you trying to do? What is `new_user`? Do you simply want to update `user` with the attributes from `new_user`?

Comment: That is correct @M.O., in my unstripped/trimmed code `update_user` is a PUT request, and `new_user` is a pydantic model with the same structure as `User`. The `db` session is injected with `Depends` in a way that opens/commits a transaction before/after the request is processed. For fastapi to correctly serialize `user.addresses` (to only contain the new addresss), I need to deassociate the old addresses, in combination with `delete-orphan`, without that `user.addresses` will still contain the old addresses and new addresses. This also avoids refetching the rows after commit.

Comment: Look into the SQLAlchemy opion [`passive_deletes`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.passive_deletes), which will make it so that objects are deleted when removed from a relationship list. Then you could just reassign `user.addresses`.

Comment: @M.O. If I'm reading the docs correctly, enabling that option would only apply if I deleted a `User` record. I think you are referring to the `delete-orphan` cascade, which marks objects for deletion when deassociated from their parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never modify list during iteration through it!

```
for address in user.addresses:
        address.user = None
```

Here you are modifying the list during the iteration through it (since you have specified `back_populates`, it will remove elements from `user.adresses` when you set `adress.user=None`).

Iterate through copy of list to avoid it:

```
for address in list(user.addresses):
        address.user = None
```